# Android Transforming json String with umlauts

Tags: android, json, gson

I want send a josn string to a php sript on a webserver.

i use this code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("street", "straße");
```

json put exactly this to the string, but the php script does not needs `straße`, it needs `stra\u00dfe`

is there any way to do this exept `String.replace()`

maybe this helps for a other solution, the php script deletes the `ß` in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send *characters* to servers, you can only send *bytes*. You need to figure out where your JSON string is being converted to a byte array and make sure that it includes a charset like UTF-8.

The JSON encoder won't convert `ß` to `\u00df` because that's not its job. As far as it is concerned, `ß` is a legal output character.